# When saving or recovering yeast is it always found in the cake or trub or lees, or is it sometimes found in the krausen?

Tags: yeast, krausen, trub

I have read various things about saving yeast when racking, which is what I intend to do soon with one small batch of cider.  I see some people just "take the cake" and I've read about a process involving the adding of room-temperature water to the remaining lees after racking, then waiting 20 minutes for the yeast to separate itself from the trub or lees.

What I've been doing so far is just putting everything into a bottle that was left over after I racked the bulk of the must out of the container.

In this case, the cake or lees on the bottom of the primary fermenter is very small, but what remains of the krausen is quite a bit larger and looks a lot like flocculated yeast.

I've shared a photo in the post, here.  Probably what's on top is just the remains of the pulp, but I am not so certain there isn't a lot of yeast there.  What I'm trying to find out ultimately with this question is:  If my goal is to recover and save the liquid yeast when I rack it, should I save what's near the top, what's on the bottom, or both?

[image: Large Krausen but Small Yeast Cake]

Answer (score 3):

"The best way to obtain yeast is to skim it from the krausen of a currently fermenting beer." -John Palmer, How to Brew

It may be tough in the jugs your are using but taking some of the krausen is the best way to get the yeast.

Source http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter6-8.html